# API Platform - UI servers endpoint definition

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

Can someone please help regarding **API Platform UI**. In the docs, I was not able to find a way to define servers here:

I want the server endpoint output to show whether on *localhost*, *dev*, or *prod*.

Can somebody help with this:

[image]

I am using it within Symfony.

I am unsure if it has something to do with the configuration in api_platform.yaml file in the routes folder:

```
api_platform:
  resource: .
  type: api_platform
  prefix: /
```

I want to configure server path like: `{domain/API_ROUTE}` where `API_ROUTE` is defined as `.env` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to decorate `OpenApiFactory`. For the how and why, it is explained in detail in a [SymfonyCast](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/api-platform-security/open-api-decoration).

For a working example: Create a file in your project `/src/ApiPlatform/OpenApiFactoryDecorator.php` with the following contents:

```
<?php

namespace App\ApiPlatform;

use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Factory\OpenApiFactoryInterface;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\Model\Server;
use ApiPlatform\OpenApi\OpenApi;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Attribute\AsDecorator;

#[AsDecorator('api_platform.openapi.factory')]
class OpenApiFactoryDecorator implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(private OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated) {}

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);

        // Create an array with your servers.
        $servers = [
            new Server("https://dev.example.com/", "Development"),
            new Server("https://prod.example.com/", "Production")
        ];

        return $openApi->withServers($servers);
    }
}
```

The above example code should work in Symfony v6.3.* with API Platform v3.1.* and provide what you need to configure the servers in your documentation.

**MIND:**

Whenever you disable documentation (as an example) in your `prod` environment, you are most likely to run into an issue with the above code. The error that could arrise whenever you have the documentation disabled: `The service "App\ApiPlatform\OpenApiFactoryDecorator" has a dependency on a non-existent service "api_platform.openapi.factory".`. In order to solve this, you should ignore the invalid refernce by using the `$onInvalid` parameter like so:

```
#[AsDecorator(
    decorates: 'api_platform.openapi.factory',
    onInvalid: ContainerInterface::IGNORE_ON_INVALID_REFERENCE, // This line is important to ignore errors whenever you disable the documentation in a specific environment.
)]
```

Comment: After this configuration, my route in UI is throwing 404 Not Found -- No route found for \"GET http://localhost/php-api/v1/examples/auth-only\" (from \"http://localhost/docs\ @Såpe