# API Platform - after localhost server configuration routes 404 Not Found

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I was registering Servers within the API Platform like:

```
readonly class OpenApiFactoryDecorator implements OpenApiFactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct(private OpenApiFactoryInterface $decorated) {}

    public function __invoke(array $context = []): OpenApi
    {
        $envServerPath = $_ENV['API_SERVER_URL'];
        $envValue = $_ENV['API_ROUTE'];

        $openApi = $this->decorated->__invoke($context);

        $servers = [
            new Server($envServerPath . $envValue,)
        ];

        return $openApi->withServers($servers);
    }
```

and got:

[image]

After doing this my routes are throwing `404 Not Found` exception..

For example:

```
new Get(
        uriTemplate: '/v1/examples/public',
        status: Response::HTTP_OK,
        controller: PublicExampleController::class,
        paginationEnabled: false,
        read: false,
        name: 'public_endpoint'
    )
```

Trying with the command:

```
 php bin/console debug:router
```

gives me the output for the route:

```
  public_endpoint                          GET      ANY      ANY    /v1/examples/public
```

Full error message:

> No route found for "GET http://localhost/php-api/v1/examples/public" (from "http://localhost/docs")",
> "class": "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Before configuring the servers in your documentation routes were working as expected. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this information could have been added to your [first thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990663/api-platform-ui-servers-endpoint-definition/76994431#76994431).

As for this question, to be honest, the error message is pretty clear. Your route is not found (eg. the URL generated is wrong). Based on your [first thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990663/api-platform-ui-servers-endpoint-definition/76994431#76994431) and combined with this information, your route should be:

`http://localhost/v1/examples/public`

and not

`http://localhost/php-api/v1/examples/public`

Like presented in my answer on your [first thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990663/api-platform-ui-servers-endpoint-definition/76994431#76994431), the server should only consist of the hostname (eg. `http://localhost`). From looking at your code, the `$_ENV['API_ROUTE']` adds the `/php-api/` part. You should not add anything else but the hostname. Any prefixes configured in API Platform (check your [first thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76990663/api-platform-ui-servers-endpoint-definition/76994431#76994431), and the provided `.yaml` config) are added automatically.

Based on the information, to solve this issue, remove the `$_ENV['API_ROUTE']` or `$envValue` from `new Server($envServerPath . $envValue,)`. Or at least make sure that you add the server with the hostname alone (eg. `new Server('http://localhost/')`).

***Additional information to answer a question in the comments:***

The above code example is **solely** for the `Swagger documentation`. Your `Swagger documentation` configuration and `API Platform` configuration are two **seperate** configurations. You should make sure they match!

For making changes to the route prefix in `API Platform` make the following changes to your `/config/routes/api_platform.yaml` should do the trick:

```
api_platform:
    resource: .
    type: api_platform
    prefix: /php-api
```

Once again: make sure your configurations match!

Comment: Ah, thanks lot for the clearification. Did not want to mix up questions..
I am asking because I want /php-api to be part of the route but I would like to include it with the server name. This is why I tried this approach Do you know how can I do it like that but still get routes to work? @Såpe

Comment: I have added additional information to my anwser. Hopefully this should do the trick for you.